# CMS as a admin page in php/mysql

Tags: php

Can you make a CMS page with just two pages. Everything I have been seeing has been using like 6 pages. All I need is an admin page and a index page. So is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All I need is an admin page and a index page. So is that possible?

Sure. You can even make a CMS page with just one page - you'd call the page with different GET parameters (like `index.php?page=index` and `index.php?page=admin`) and build conditions into the file to do one thing or the other, depending on what the value of `page` is.

The question is how much sense this makes architecture-wise - the bigger a source code file becomes, the harder it is to manage. Splitting up larger classes and source files usually makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its posible. If you would like to use MySQL take a look on http://www.slimframework.com/. This is very simple framework which saves your development time.

Comment: well I am only suppose to use textpad and navicat.

Comment: Ah, ok. Anyway you could use it without mysql also of course.

Comment: I have the admin page and index page almost done just trying to figure out the code I need for it is all.

Comment: The first answer from Pekka more suitable then. Some tip a bit. You could use htaccess for friendly URL like /admin/page/1/.